# Some Japanese characters not displaying correctly

Tags: php, email, utf-8, email-headers

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to parse an email, and then post the email content to a website.  The email may contain Japanese or English.  The Japanese displays 99% correctly on the website, but every now and then a character will be swapped for another, or it will display as garbage.

Here's the code being used to get the proper encoding for the email body-

```
$post->content = quoted_printable_decode($parser->getMessageBody('text'));

$isISO2022 = $parser->isISO2022();

$post->content = ($isISO2022)
             ? mb_convert_encoding($post->content, 'UTF-8', 'iso-2022-jp')
             : mb_convert_encoding($post->content, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($post->content));

$post->save();
```

The parser's isISO2022 function:

```
public function isISO2022() {
        $isISO2022 = false;

        foreach ($this->parts as $part) {
            if (isset($part['headers']['content-type']) && preg_match('/iso-2022-jp/i',$part['headers']['content-type'])) {
                $isISO2022 = true;
            }
        }

        return $isISO2022;
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Added:
I have heard that there are some specific characters that are not supported by iso-2022-jp, and you should use iso-2022-jp-ms instead, but when I try to use iso-2022-jp-ms, it says invalid encoding.  It also seems to me that the characters I've seen it not display correctly are basic characters, and should be universally supported.